# Non programmable method to edit indicators

Tags: 12.04, indicator

How could i edit or change some behaviors or appearance in indicators?!

I know that there is questions about before but the questions is about creating new one so its not duplicate :)

I need to learn if an edit can be done easily

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way I could think to change the "appearance" of an indicator is to change its icon.  Other than that, you'd have to edit the underlying code/script...which is the best way to learn!